English chat room frozen
http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1984/ is currently frozen.
Can it be unfrozen please?
I promise not to post any more questions about turtle excrement soup in chat!

I hadn't noticed it got frozen. Now everything is back to its normal temperature! 

I wasn't aware of that chatroom until I searched for "chat" on the Meta site. The room is currently frozen, with a message saying, "The last message was posted 398 days ago." (I don't think that unfreezing it again will be useful, though.) The other chatroom is also very quiet.
